# convert integer to 32-bit binary in c

Tags: c, binary, converters

I'm writing a program to convert an integer to 32-bit binary. The problem is with the output - it comes backwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long number, binary, num2;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%ld", &number);

    for (num2 = (number * 2) / 2; num2 > 0; num2 /= 2) {
        binary = num2 % 2;
        printf("%ld", binary);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

So if I put '6' it shows as 011 and it has to be 110

Also, how do I output the rest of '0's? So that the whole output in this case would be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110
```

Comment: number is an integer so (number * 2) / 2 is equal to number ! (assuming no overflow, and that the compiler doesn't optimise that away.

Comment: Also, I typed your question title into a search engine, and unsurprisingly there were many hits!

Comment: @MitchWheat I bet most of them cause undefined behaviour due to integer overflow

Answer (score 2):

You compute digits starting from the right, which is why your output shows the right-most digit first.  Here is a way that starts from the left, using a bitmask, and does not convert your value to unsigned which may change the bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    long number;
    if ( 1 != scanf("%ld", &number) )
        return 1;

    // sign bit  (cannot use 1L left-shift as that causes UB)
    putchar( '0' + (number < 0) );

    // value bits
    for (long bit = 1L << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof number - 2); bit; bit >>= 1)
        putchar( '0' + !!(number & bit) );

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the binary number, you should print the bits backwards. Watch this:

> 6 (10):
>
> 6 / 2 = 3, rem => 0
>
> 3 / 2 = 1, rem => 1
>
> 1 / 2 = 0, rem => 1
>
> Hence 6 (2) = 110

You are printing it the forward order which will give you 011. So you should keep the binary bits by putting them in a variable and finally print them back.

Try This

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
  long number, binary, num2;
  int i = 0, j;
  char num[100];

  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%ld", &number);

  while (number != 0){
    num[i] = num2 % 2;
    number /= 2;
    i++;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
    if (j > i) {
      printf("0");
    }
    else {
      printf("%c", num[i]);
      i--
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so much easier to use a recursive function for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void printInBinary(long num, int bit)
{
   if ( bit >= 8*sizeof(num) )
   {
      return;
   }

   printInBinary(num/2, bit+1);
   printf("%ld", num%2);

   if ( bit%8 == 0 )
   {
      printf(" ");
   }
   if ( bit == 0 )
   {
      printf("\n");
   }
}

int main()
{
   int y = 31;
   uint32_t x1 = (1 << y );
   uint32_t x2 = (1u << y );
   printf("x1: %u\n", x1);
   printInBinary(x1, 0);

   printf("x2: %u\n", x2);
   printInBinary(x2, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
x1: 2147483648
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
x2: 2147483648
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

**PS** If you used `uint32_t` for `num` instead of `long`, you will get the 32 bits of output.

Comment: Nice! There's just a small problem, this will print the value in reverse bit order. You might want to switch it up to tail recursion to print in the same bit order as the original value... :)

Comment: @corecase, it prints the high order bits first. Does that not make more sense?

Comment: Assuming a typical host machine, the bit order is usually little endian, so the most significant bits tend to be the left-most bits. I would personally prefer to print out the bits in the same order that they are actually represented on my machine, so this would be in reverse of that order... It's kind of a preference thing and it also depends on the endianness of the machine you're running the code on, but based on the context of this question little endian seems like a more reasonable assumption. It is a pretty minor detail though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple portable implementation for 32-bit numbers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    long input;  // at least 32 bits
    unsigned long number;
    int i;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    if (scanf("%ld", &input) != 1) 
        return 1;
    /* copy the bit pattern to an unsigned long */
    memcpy(&number, &input, sizeof number);
    for (i = 32; i-- > 0;) {
        if (i > 0 && (i & 7) == 0)
            putchar(' ');
        putchar('0' + (int)((number >> i) & 1));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply examine the bits in the order in which you want them output. I have used a `unsigned long` cast for the shifting, because the result of shifting bits of a signed value into the sign bit is undefined.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    int main() {
        long number = 0;
        int i;

        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%ld", &number);
        for(i=0; i<sizeof(number)*CHAR_BIT; i++) {
            if (number < 0)
                printf ("1");
            else
                printf ("0");
            if ((i % CHAR_BIT) == CHAR_BIT - 1)
                printf (" ");
            number = (long)((unsigned long)(number) << 1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Program output:

```
Enter an integer: 6
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110
```

Comment: You do avoid UB; however `(long)((unsigned long)(number) <<= 1)` is implementation-defined which may raise a signal.

Comment: @MattMcNabb my first solution was to assign the `long` to, and work with `unsigned long` throughout, but the explanation was harder to phrase.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ah, just spotted the incorrect `<<=` and edited it out, thank you.

Comment: Hmm we both had the same blind spot, I mean that the `<<` version causes implementation-defined behaviour which may raise a signal.  (The `<<=` version was ill-formed). I suppose this algorithm just has to rely on the implementation being "sensible" with its decision there.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    // Assuming 32 bit architecture.
    unsigned long number;

    // Initialize a null-terminated char-array
    // of zeros (ASCII value 48).
    char binary[33] = {[0 ... 31] = 48, [32] = 0}; 

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%lu", &number);

    for(int i = 0; number > 0; ++i) {
        binary[31 - i] = number % 2;
        number /= 2;
    }
    printf("%s\n", binary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `'0'` instead of hard coding the  ASCII value `48`. Furthermore you should avoid the non portable gcc extension `[0 ... 31]`. Finally, `binary[31 - i] = number % 2` does not produce a digit value, you must add `'0'`.